# JavaScript, вопросы новичка. Области видимости, анонимные ф-и и цикл

Tags: javascript

> why go() is not defined? Потому что анонимная?

```
var fo = function go(){return 23;};
typeof go();
```

> почему возвращается 2? и подскажите что это за конструкция такая после
>   равно, еще и запятая между функциями?

```
var f1 = (function f1(){return "1";}, function g1(){return 2;})();
console.log(typeof f1);
console.log(f1);
```

> почему в следующем коде получаем - NaN?

```
function get() {
    var a = 2;
    function summ() {
        var b = 3;
        b = b + a;
        var a = 3;
        return b;
    }
    return summ();
}
console.log(get());
```

> следующий код, почему s = 49? Теряю цепочку вычисления(

```
function sum1(a,b) {
    s = a + b;
    return s;
}
function product(a, b) {
    var p = a * b;
    return p;
}
s = 2;
p = 5;
p = sum1(s,p);
s = product(p,s);
document.write("S = " + s + ", P = " + p);
```

> почему ошибка myFunction is not a function (anonymous) В myResult передаётся код ф-и без имени, поэтому она воспринимается переменной как анонимная?

```
function myFunction(){
    return "Hi";
}
var myFunction = 1;
var myResult = myFunction();
console.log(myResult);
```

> Какая самая оптимальная конструкция для перебора значений в массиве? Чтобы избежать "холиваров" уточню, оптимальная касательно производительности. Если можно, указывайте вместо производительности другую характеристику и оптимальную для неё конструкцию.

```
for(var i=0; i<enumerable.length;i++){
    enumerable[i];
}

for(var key in enumerable){
    enumerable[key];
}

var i=enumerable.length;
while (i--) {
    enumerable[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why go() is not defined? Потому что анонимная?

```
var fo = function go(){return 23;};
typeof go();
```

Нет. В данном случае `go` - это не определение функции, а функциональное выражение. Это значит, что область видимости `go` ограничена только самой функцией. [Подробнее в справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)

> почему возвращается 2? и подскажите что это за конструкция такая после равно, еще и запятая между функциями?

```
var f1 = (function f1(){return "1";}, function g1(){return 2;})();
console.log(typeof f1);
console.log(f1);
```

В данном случае опять используются [*function expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), а также [оператор запятая](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F) и [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (когда функция вызывается сразу после описания)

> почему в следующем коде получаем - NaN?

```
function get() {
    var a = 2;
    function summ() {
        var b = 3;
        b = b + a;
        var a = 3;
        return b;
    }
    return summ();
}
console.log(get());
```

В яваскрипте существует такое понятие, как [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), то есть пример выше можно переписать так:

```
function summ() {
    var a,b;
    b = 3;
    b = b + a;
    a = 3;
    return b;
}
```

Значение неинициализированных переменных - *undefined*, а сложение *undefined* с числом дает *NaN*.

> следующий код, почему s = 49? Теряю цепочку вычисления(

```
function sum1(a,b) {
    s = a + b;
    return s;
}
function product(a, b) {
    var p = a * b;
    return p;
}
s = 2;
p = 5;
p = sum1(s,p);
s = product(p,s);
document.write("S = " + s + ", P = " + p);
```

Стоит используя отладчик пройтись по шагам и посмотреть значения переменных.

> почему ошибка myFunction is not a function (anonymous) В myResult передаётся код ф-и без имени, поэтому она воспринимается переменной как анонимная?

```
function myFunction(){
    return "Hi";
}
var myFunction = 1;
var myResult = myFunction();
console.log(myResult);
```

Здесь ничего не рассматривается как *анонимная*. Просто при объявлении переменной ее имя перекрывает имя функции.
Вообще тут могут быть интересные результаты в зависимости от расположения `var`, присваивания и попытки вызова функции.

> Какая самая оптимальная конструкция для перебора значений в массиве? Чтобы избежать "холиваров" уточню, оптимальная касательно производительности. Если можно, указывайте вместо производительности другую характеристику и оптимальную для неё конструкцию.

```
for(var i=0; i<enumerable.length;i++){
    enumerable[i];
}

for(var key in enumerable){
    enumerable[key];
}

var i=enumerable.length;
while (i--) {
    enumerable[i];
}
```

Вообще говоря, второй тип: `for..in` вообще не рекомендуется для работы с массивами.
Разница же между двумя оставшимися весьма условна, за исключением того, что в первом варианте свойство `length` берется на каждой итерации.
Сказать какая из реализаций однозначно производительней - не возможно, так как это зависит от слишком многих условий, может оказаться что в разных браузерах может лидировать либо одна, либо вторая, либо они будут показывать примерно одинаковый результат. Чтобы узнать для конкретного компьютера и браузера можно выполнить тест например на [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/)

Также, не исключено, что конкретно в приведенном примере оптимизатор может вообще выкинуть циклы, так как внутри них ничего не делается и не меняется.

Answer (score 3):

Вы переменной присвоили функцию, называется «Function Expression» (функциональное выражение), поэтому извне этой переменной она не видна.

Пишут:

> Function Declaration – функция, объявленная в основном потоке кода.
>   Function Expression – объявление функции в контексте какого-либо выражения, например присваивания.

```
var fo = function go(){return 23;};
typeof go();//puk-puk
typeof fo();//o yes
```

Имена функций и переменных должны отличаться, вы переменной присваиваете значение 1, больше это не функция.

```
function myFunction(){
    return "Hi";
}
var myFunction = 1;
var myResult = myFunction();
console.log(myResult);
```

Дальше, 49 получается потому что вы в функции `sum1()` присвоили глобальной `s` значение 7.

```
function sum1(a,b) {
    s = a + b;// глобальная s=7 
    return s;
}
function product(a, b) {
    var p = a * b;
    return p;
}
s = 2;
p = 5;
p = sum1(s,p);
s = product(p,s); // p=7, s=7
document.write("S = " + s + ", P = " + p);
```

Тут вы `var a` объявили позже её использования, поэтому её значение в строке выше undefined.

```
function get() {
    var a = 2;
    function summ() {
        var b = 3;
        b = b + a;
        var a = 3;
        return b;
    }
    return summ();
}
console.log(get());
```

Comment: ох-ох-ох, _Присваивать переменной надо анонимную функцию_ - не **надо**, а **можно**

Comment: @Grundy подправил.

Answer (score 3):

> why go() is not defined? Потому что анонимная?

```
var fo = function go(){return 23;};
typeof go();
```

В этом случае вы используете именованое функциональное выражение, при этом вызов функции по имени не происходит, этот способ написания функции применяется для передачи функции поссылке, если более подробно, почитайте
[сдесь](http://learn.javascript.ru/named-function-expression)

> почему возвращается 2? и подскажите что это за конструкция такая после равно, еще и запятая между функциями?

```
var f1 = (function f1(){return "1";}, function g1(){return 2;})();
console.log(typeof f1);
console.log(f1);
```

Во втором вопросе почитайте про оператор запятая, он возвращает последнее значение в данном случае функция g1

> почему в следующем коде получаем - NaN?

```
function get() {
    var a = 2;
    function summ() {
        var b = 3;
        b = b + a;
        var a = 3;
        return b;
    }
    return summ();
}
console.log(get());
```

В третьем вопросе, я думаю вы используете именованю функцию, которая не имеет доступа к переменным внешней функции, но это лично мое предположение

> следующий код, почему s = 49? Теряю цепочку вычисления(

```
function sum1(a,b) {
    s = a + b;
    return s;
}
function product(a, b) {
    var p = a * b;
    return p;
}
s = 2;
p = 5;
p = sum1(s,p);
s = product(p,s);
document.write("S = " + s + ", P = " + p);
```

Четвертый, по мере того как вы вызываете функции меняются значения s и p, так как в функциях вы используете глобальные переменные, по этому они изменяются.

> почему ошибка myFunction is not a function (anonymous) В myResult передаётся код ф-и без имени, поэтому она воспринимается переменной как анонимная?

```
 function myFunction(){
    return "Hi";
}
var myFunction = 1;
var myResult = myFunction();
console.log(myResult);
```

Пятое: вы попросту изменяете значение с функции на число, переменная и функция должны быть названы по разному.

С шестым о переборе не могу помочь. Пользуйтесь тем что удобно.

Comment: возможно стоит вопросы скопировать в ответ, а то первое, пятое, и т.д. проблематично соотнести с конкретным вопрос, все-таки вопросов много и каждый раз туда сюда страницу крутить не очень.